# How to locate a string among all files under a directory?

Tags: shell

I have a directory containing a bunch of header files from a library. I would like to see how "Uint32" is defined.

So, I need a way to scan over all those header files and print out lines with "Uint32".

I guess grep could help, but I'm new to shell scripts.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways.

```
grep -r --include="*.c" Unit32
```

is one way.

Another is:

```
find . -name "*.c" | xargs grep Unit32
```

If you have spaces in the file names, the latter can be problematic.

```
find . -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 grep Unit32
```

will solve that typically.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple `grep` will be fine:

```
grep "Uint32" *.h*
```

This will search both `*.h` and `*.hpp` header files.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst using `grep` is fine, for navigating code you may also want to investigate [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) (a source-code aware `grep` variant), and/or [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) (which integrates with vi or emacs and allows navigation through code in your editor)

`ack` in particular is very nice, since it'll navigate through directory hierarchies, and only work on specific types of files (so for C it'll interrogate .c and .h files, but ignore SCM revision directories, backup files etc.)

Of course, you really need some form of IDE to give you complete navigation over the codebase.

Comment: Thanks bro. I'll check 'ack' for sure. But I do hate IDE's since I believe that they make people dumber and dumber lol.